# Component level service in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angularjs-components

I'm looking for a way to implement a component level service whose scope is limited to the component and not to the full application, so that for every instance of this component I'll have a separate instance of this service.

Tried creating a service and instantiated it using new keyword(not registered in angular module) in the controller but then I have to provide all the dependencies manually or have to use $injector to get the dependencies in this service class.

Also to make this approach testable I need to expose this property so that one can mock it.

Would like to know more cleaner approach to achieve this where I can inject it in the controller.

I know this is possible in Angular...but I have to achieve it in AngularJs.

Answer (score 0):

Create an angular .factory instead of a .service, inject as normal and instantiate with a new factory() in component. You should be able to find many examples of creating an angular factory with prototypes and returning the factory function back.

Comment: But factories are also singelton..you need to have a function there and then you need to ask to get new instance through this function...same can be achieved through services...I don't want to create a separate function for this...trying to find a way which is more implicit and controlled by angular itself

Comment: Services, factory and providers, can be used to do anything you need in an application. Don&#39;t fight the core features stick with it. Angular doesn&#39;t understand anything that isnt factory, service, provider as fact as injectables are considered. On that note you can also I just values constant etc. Perhaps an angular value with a function could help here.